# Getting errors while creating a custom terrain editor (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I created two scripts called "CustomTerrain" and "CustomTerrainEditor". Here is the code for the latter:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using EditorGUITable;

[CustomEditor(typeOf(CustomTerrain))] // Links editor code in here with CustomTerrain.cs
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class CustomTerrainEditor : Editor
{
    void OnEnable() {}

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {} // The GUI we will see in the inspector
}
```

Here are the 2 errors I get:
[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change typeOf to typeof.

And next if CustomTerrain in another namespace, add this space to your script.

Comment: Thank! Just changing typeOf to typeof fixed it!

Comment: @IzzyDev Mark this answer as accepted if it helps you